# TF History will not use my servername (Ignoring the /server option)

Tags: command-line, tfs

I am trying to run the following command against my TFS 2008 server:

> > TF history /server:MyTFSServer /recursive “$/MyTFSProject/Folder”

When I run I get this:

> > Ignoring the /server option

It then complains about workspace.  The workspace part I get (it is trying to use my current folder to establish the TFS Server.  Where I am running from is not mapped so it can't connect.  For my needs going tot he right folder will not help.)

But WHY WHY WHY does it not like my /server option?

I have tried /s, /server and -s.  None of them work.  I have checked and double checked the spelling of my server name.  I have checked to make sure that the tf.exe I am running is the TFS 2008 version.

I am so confused and getting a bit frustrated.

(The sad thing is I had this working last week.  I ran several history commands without any issues.  I don't have the text from those commands, so I don't know what I did different, but I know it CAN work.)

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you get this message it's because the /server parameter is unnecessary - that is, the client has determined your workspace and server information from the path you gave it.  This should only happen with local paths, however, not with server paths.  Can you confirm that you're only using server paths in your commands?

Comment: I am using the $/ path notation.  It is a server path (copied from the source explorer)